# Como atualizar ListView após excluir item?

Tags: android

Estou excluindo o item do ListView e funciona normal, só que o método notifyDataSetChanged(); não está funcionando no meu ListView e o item continua aparecendo mesmo após excluir. O que posso fazer nesse caso ?

classe que cria o adapter

```
public class ListaNotificacoes extends Fragment{

View minha_view;

public ArrayList<ItensDaLista> lista_menu;
public ListView lista_notify;
public static ItensDoAdaptador itens_adaptador;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    minha_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_notificacoes, container, false);
    return minha_view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    recupera_tarefa();
}

public void recupera_tarefa(){

    try {
        Cursor cursor = banco_dados.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lista_notificacoes order by id DESC", null);

        //recupera os ids da coluna
        int indiceColunaId = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
        int indiceColunaTexto = cursor.getColumnIndex("texto_notificacao");
        int indiceColunaHora = cursor.getColumnIndex("hora_notificacao");

        lista_menu = new ArrayList<>();

        itens_adaptador = new ItensDoAdaptador(getActivity(), lista_menu);
        lista_notify = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_notify);
        lista_notify.setAdapter(itens_adaptador);

        //lista_notify.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.empty_view));


        //listar as notificações
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor != null) {
            String teste = cursor.getString(indiceColunaId);
            lista_menu.add(new ItensDaLista(teste.toString(),cursor.getString(indiceColunaTexto),cursor.getString(indiceColunaHora),R.drawable.delete));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

classe que está executando o método de exclusão

```
public class ItensDoAdaptador extends ArrayAdapter<ItensDaLista> {

public ItensDoAdaptador(Activity context, ArrayList<ItensDaLista> iten_drawer) {
    // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
    // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
    // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
    // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
    super(context,0, iten_drawer);
}

public ItensDoAdaptador(Activity context, int count){
    super(context,0,count);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item_notify, parent, false);

    }

    final ItensDaLista itens_adapter = getItem(position);

    TextView imagem_drawer = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.numero_notificacao);
    imagem_drawer.setText(itens_adapter.getNumero_notificacao());

    ImageView imagem_drawer_2 = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.botao_deletar);
    imagem_drawer_2.setImageResource(itens_adapter.getId_imagem());
    imagem_drawer_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            remover_tarefa(valueOf(itens_adapter.getNumero_notificacao()));
            itens_adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    TextView texto_notify = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.texto_notificacao_list);
    texto_notify.setText(itens_adapter.getTexto());

    TextView hora_notify = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.texto_hora_list);
    hora_notify.setText("Hora: " + itens_adapter.getHora());

    return listItemView;
}

private void remover_tarefa(Integer id){
    try {
        banco_dados.execSQL("DELETE FROM lista_notificacoes WHERE id="+id);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

O seu Adapter está ligado a um ArrayList. O notifyDataSetChanged() só vai ter efeito se você remover um item desse ArrayList e depois chamar o método. No seu caso, você está fazendo isso depois de deletar linhas do banco de dados, que não está ligado ao Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ItensDoAdaptador extends ArrayAdapter<ItensDaLista> {

public ItensDoAdaptador(Activity context, ArrayList<ItensDaLista> ten_drawer) {
// Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
// the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
// Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
// going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
super(context,0, iten_drawer);
}

public ItensDoAdaptador(Activity context, int count){
super(context,0,count);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
View listItemView = convertView;
if (listItemView == null) {
    listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.list_item_notify, parent, false);

}

final ItensDaLista itens_adapter = getItem(position);

TextView imagem_drawer = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.numero_notificacao);
imagem_drawer.setText(itens_adapter.getNumero_notificacao());

ImageView imagem_drawer_2 = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.botao_deletar);
imagem_drawer_2.setImageResource(itens_adapter.getId_imagem());
imagem_drawer_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        remover_tarefa(valueOf(itens_adapter.getNumero_notificacao()));
```

> A Ultima vez que fiz erra rotina, estava usando o CursorAdapter, e somente fiz a Req-Query da Seguinte Forma.
>
> `Cursor cursor = banco_dados.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lista_notificacoes order by id DESC", null);`
>
> `changeCursor(cursor);`
>
> `notifyDataSetChanged();`
>
> Quando estamos dentro de um Adapter não precisamos de um Objeto para chamar o notifyDataSetChanged();

```
        itens_adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
});

TextView texto_notify = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.texto_notificacao_list);
texto_notify.setText(itens_adapter.getTexto());

TextView hora_notify = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.texto_hora_list);
hora_notify.setText("Hora: " + itens_adapter.getHora());

return listItemView;
}

private void remover_tarefa(Integer id){
try {
    banco_dados.execSQL("DELETE FROM lista_notificacoes WHERE id="+id);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```